# I am trying do utilize the COUNT() function unsuccessfully

Tags: sql, count, view

I am constructing a view which is supposed to give me the number of students working on any given assignment. Here is what I have so far:

```
CREATE VIEW v_count AS
    SELECT assignment_no, COUNT(*)
    FROM assignment WHERE
```

Comment: Is some part of query missing ?

Comment: So, what's the problem?

Comment: I could'nt figure out how to add the students in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your statement to:

```
 CREATE VIEW v_count AS
 SELECT assignment_no, COUNT(*) as ct
 FROM assignment
 group by assignment_no
```

Comment: Thank you, Ormoz!  I was able to run it but I am getting an error 'no column 2 was specified for v_count'.  I cannot figure out how to explicitly tell the view to include students working on each assignment.

Comment: @oakrun I changed the statement. It missed the column name.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW v_count AS
   SELECT assignment_no, COUNT(*) as CountOfStudents
   FROM assignment
     group by assignment_no
```

try this..

Comment: For some reason the MSQL Server doesn't like the 'OR REPLACE'  syntax.